# Appending conditions in where clause not working

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I am trying to append condition to where clause .But the string which contains the condition is not working .I am not getting any error but the condition is not fully applied in the query

Here's the query.I am passing CLINIC_ID and taleEnd to my stored procedure.taleEnd will include a condition or more like this - "and DOS between '2011-09-08' and '2011-10-08'"

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON C.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID AND C.CLAIM_ID = VP.CLAIM_ID
  JOIN C ON P.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID  AND P.PATIENT_ID = VP.PATIENT_ID
  JOIN D ON I.CLINIC_ID = C.CLINIC_ID  AND I.INSURANCE_ID= C.PRIMARY_INSURANCE_ID
  JOIN E ON B.CLINIC_ID = I.CLINIC_ID  AND B.BUSINESS_ID= I.COMPANY_ID
 WHERE (VP.STATUS = 3 OR VP.STATUS = 5)
   AND VP.PRIMARY_PAID = 0
   AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING > 0
   AND C.PRIMARY_PAYER_ID > 0
   AND C.HIDEN = 0
   AND VP.CLINIC_ID = CLINIC_ID + taleEnd
```

The problem is that only clinic_id and not DOS is applied when i run the stored procedure.I tried concat ,set but nothing worked.i didn't got any error but the result do not applies DOS.Can any one help me please.

@Devart This is the store procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `PRIMARY_INSURANCE_AGING`(CLINIC_ID INT,taleEnd TEXT)
BEGIN
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS PRIMARY_TEMP;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE PRIMARY_TEMP
SELECT *     
  FROM A   
  JOIN B ON C.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID AND C.CLAIM_ID = VP.CLAIM_ID   
  JOIN C ON P.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID AND P.PATIENT_ID = VP.PATIENT_ID   
  JOIN D ON I.CLINIC_ID = C.CLINIC_ID  AND I.INSURANCE_ID= C.PRIMARY_INSURANCE_ID   
  JOIN E ON B.CLINIC_ID = I.CLINIC_ID  AND B.BUSINESS_ID= I.COMPANY_ID 
 WHERE (VP.STATUS = 3 OR VP.STATUS =5 ) 
   AND VP.PRIMARY_PAID = 0   
   AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING > 0   
   AND C.PRIMARY_PAYER_ID > 0   
   AND C.HIDEN = 0  
   AND VP.CLINIC_ID = CLINIC_ID + taleEnd;

   END
```

This is the usage of Prepare statement

```
SET @A = CONCAT(34847," and DOS between '2011-09-08' and '2011-10-08'");
PREPARE STMT FROM '
SELECT *
  FROM A
  JOIN B ON C.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID AND C.CLAIM_ID = VP.CLAIM_ID
  JOIN C ON P.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID AND P.PATIENT_ID = VP.PATIENT_ID
  JOIN D ON I.CLINIC_ID = C.CLINIC_ID AND I.INSURANCE_ID= C.PRIMARY_INSURANCE_ID
  JOIN E ON B.CLINIC_ID = I.CLINIC_ID AND B.BUSINESS_ID= I.COMPANY_ID
  WHERE (VP.STATUS = 3 OR VP.STATUS = 5)
  AND VP.PRIMARY_PAID = 0
  AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING > 0
  AND C.PRIMARY_PAYER_ID > 0
  AND C.HIDEN = 0
  AND VP.CLINIC_ID ? ';

EXECUTE STMT USING @A;
```

Comment: Aha, I see what you are trying to do, which is to pass in additional filter criteria, including the field name, to the procedure, which you want to be applied to the query during execution. In that case, I'm not sure about how to do that I'm afraid, but would be interested in the answer should you get one!!!

Comment: @Dave Rix  yes you are absolutely right..but i cant get a way out from this...:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Dave Rix about the variable and field names, they should be different.

If you want to append additional string (like - *and DOS between '2011-09-08' and '2011-10-08'*) to the query, then you should use a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON C.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID AND C.CLAIM_ID = VP.CLAIM_ID
JOIN C ON P.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID AND P.PATIENT_ID = VP.PATIENT_ID
JOIN D ON I.CLINIC_ID = C.CLINIC_ID AND I.INSURANCE_ID= C.PRIMARY_INSURANCE_ID
JOIN E ON B.CLINIC_ID = I.CLINIC_ID AND B.BUSINESS_ID= I.COMPANY_ID WHERE (VP.STATUS = 3 OR VP.STATUS =5 ) AND VP.PRIMARY_PAID = 0
AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING > 0
AND C.PRIMARY_PAYER_ID > 0
AND C.HIDEN = 0
AND VP.CLINIC_ID = ?'; -- ? will be supplied with procedure argument clinic_id_value; where clinic_id_value is a renamed procedure argument

IF taleEnd IS NOT NULL THEN
  @query = CONCAT(@query, ' ', taleEnd);
END IF;

SET @clinic_id_value = clinic_id_value; -- copy procedure argument to the local variable
PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
EXECUTE STMT USING @clinic_id_value;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
```

Comment: no i have used the prepared statement also .But it too doesnot works.

Comment: Check your query with added `taleEnd`. Does it work? Execute it separately.

Comment: .no the taleEnd is dynamic..there may be a taleEnd condition or it may end with clinic_id.so only way is to append it with the static query.

Comment: I understand that taleEnd is dynamic. It should work with prepared statements. But, firstly - try to execute and test your query with taleEnd condition and check the result.

Comment: thanks for considering .I had executed it seperately and it worked and gave the exact result.

Comment: It means that something wrong with prepared statement usage. Can you show the code with prapared statement?

Comment: @ Devart I have pasted the prepare statement..would you please consider that too.

Comment: You cannot set condition to the variable in USING clause. Try to built the whole query using CONCAT function.

Comment: Great... it worked thanks very much for your fix..i was struggling with this for two three days..once again thanks for the fix...:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing in `CLINIC_ID` to the stored procedure, and trying to use that within the procedure, I think (without being able to check properly), that there is confusion between the variable `CLINIC_ID` and the field `VP.CLINIC_ID`.

Try changing the variable name in the procedure to something unique.

Comment: no actually clinic_id is working the other condition ie the taleEnd is not getting right.

Comment: Ok, we need to see the entire `CREATE PROCEDURE` or `CREATE FUNCTION` statement, and how you use it would also be useful...

Comment: @ Dave Rix I have added the store procedure.Will that be enough for you.